# Parse an Index of Textbook

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I would like to parse an index of a textbook but the format is consistently inconsistent. Any suggestions as to how to handle these entries.

Wordy word
words, ##-###
Wordy words, ###
Parent word, ##
child words, ##
words that mean nothing without parent, ###
more words with no meaning w/out parent, ##, ##
Words,
`##, ###-###, ###`
Parenting Word, ###-###
child words, ##
Proper noun associated with parenting but otherwise no meaning, ###

The goal is to be able to sort them by first appearing page number and append child's text to the parent's text and using the child's page number; replacing the old child. Such that `Parenting Word child words, ##` exists.

Comment: each bullet is a new line, format restrictions. :\

Comment: Two spaces at the end of a line will force a line break. If you need formatting that includes indentation, which I think you do, then formatting as a code block is the way to go.

Comment: I just looked at the indexes of a couple of programming books that I have on my desk, and all I can say is, "Good luck with that!" One suggestion is to parse backwards from the end of each line looking for digits, spaces, commas, and dashes. The end of the wordy word is the first character that is none of those. But even that is fragile, if some of the wordy words contain digits.

Comment: Chore graph, 172–174, 202  
barriers, 243f  
loop, 242, 243f  
macro dataflow, 204  
sketch, shellsort, 190  
Warshall’s algorithm, 176f  

Or why in the world pages would have letters associated with them. However I'm willing to work with these individually, the bulk is in the format I mentioned in the question. (1700 lines is going to take a bit to do by hand though)

Comments don't have formatting?

Comment: Lol, that's even worse. So my approach to this kind of problem is to write a parser that handles the typical case. Then parse the index (storing the results in memory) and then output the results into a text file, attempting to reproduce the index exactly. Then do a file comparison to find all of the exceptions to the rules.

Comment: Comments have very limited formatting like **bold**, *italics*, or `code`.

Comment: I know questions are suppose to have an "answer" and we are "discussing", but what about trimming the index down by Character. Have a file for A, a file for B, etc. That would limit the number of proper noun problems. As for verifying the content, that's what Google is for. (*-`ω´- )人(*-`ω´- )

Comment: I will upload my answer for the badge if no one else comes up with something before that.

Answer (score 1):

I'll come back and edit the order and upload a diagram.

- if entry has a page number (only important for parents with children)
- if entry is alphabetical to entry before and after it (will catch some of the proper nouns)
- if entry is capitalized (catches all but proper nouns)
- fill in parents with children information upon reaching a new plausible parent (capital, not alphabetical with that last child, possibly looking at page numbers for large gaps)
- page numbers can only have the 'f' appended to them to indicate figure. <- abuse this with floating point notation.
- build linked list of parents (to help catch proper nouns slipping by)

  - parent information should be dynamic so that if a proper noun does get classified as a parent when it should be a child, it can be converted quickly to correct parent.

To help identify if it's a proper noun, compare page numbers, if the same page number or within a reasonable range is mentioned in the previous parent or parent's children, flag as potential proper noun to be reviewed by human.

- Set a delimiter to a comma with some magic around it to look for " [0-9]" after and a word before.  And we know that [0-9]f?\n[A-Z] ends the entry.

This isn't at all fast but for <10,000 lines of text, it shouldn't be too difficult. Brute force!